# Conditional Listener Stalling

Tags: javascript

I have a click listener in my JavaScript app that is only supposed to run when a condition is true. If the condition is true, then it sets the flag to false, runs code, and when that code is complete the flag is set to true. That aspect works great. However, if I click while the condition is false, the listener's code will still run and the log I placed in the function to test the flag isn't run until after the flag is true again. Here's the listener:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(quoteReady());
  if (!quoteReady()) return;
  console.log('success');
  ready.innerHTML = 'X';
  if(background.classList.contains('inactive')){
    background.classList.remove('inactive');
    secondBackground.classList.add('inactive');
    resetPage(secondBackground, secondText)
  }
  else{
    background.classList.add('inactive');
    secondBackground.classList.remove('inactive');
    resetPage(background, text);
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot click "while" the synchronous code is running. It takes only an instant, and the next click event will be handled when the first one is done. They never run at the same time, so you don't need that flag you described at all.

Comment: Please show your code for `quoteReady` and `resetPage`.

Comment: What flag are you referring to specifically, that `inactive` class on `background`?